# Rendering components dynamically using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an application that runs in 3 different countries (something close to an e-commerce). Each country has a development team that can change some specific `component` to fit the needs. I'm thinking about passing the components through context, but how to pick the `Form-US` or the `Form-UK`, for example? (Thinking that importing dynamically it's not possible in React)

My App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import UserInput from './common/UserInput'

class App extends React.Component {

  getChildContext () {
    return {
      input: UserInput
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
  input: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default App
```

And I pick the component when needed like that:

```
render () {
    const Input = this.context.input
    return (
        <Input placeholder='Input Test'/>
    )
}
```

That Works just fine, but its that a good practice? It's there a better way to do it and how can I add a component with a specific name to that structure?

Comment: Using context is dangerous unless you know exactly what you're doing. What about having the child import all possible components, and having the parent pass which component to use as a prop?

Comment: @dshapiro Its also a possibility. What about using `require('Component-${COUNTRY}')` instead of importing all possible childs?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with require to say for sure whether that would work. If the teams only need different components at compile time (as it sounds), then you also have the option of doing something in the build process. For instance, you could have a "country" config option that causes that country's component to be exported as `Input` and then always have the parent use `Input`.

Comment: That sounds even better! Do you have any articles or something like that to send me?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. I don't know what your build process is, but I'd bet webpack is capable of something like that. If my boss were demanding this today, I'd do what's in the answer I'm about to post.

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in the comments, there are smarter ways to do this. But if I needed a solution to this today, here's what I'd do:

index.js for 'Input'

```
import ComponentUS from './Component-US';
import ComponentBR from './Component-BR';
import ComponentAG from './Component-AG';
import config from '../config.json';

let thingToExport;
if (config.country === 'US') {
  thingToExport = ComponentUS;
} else if (config.country === 'BR') {
  thingToExport = ComponentBR;
} else {
  thingToExport = ComponentAG;
}
export default thingToExport;
```

And then the parent can just import `Input` from index.js.